# "that enables vs. enabling"

Tags: word-choice, phrases, verbs

I'm describing an app.

The sentence is

> X is an app that enables you to do Y

I think it doesn't sound really well.
Would

> X is an app enabling you to do Y

be better? Is this form OK at all?

Do you have other ideas?

Comment: Both are OK, I personally prefer the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both forms you used would be ok, but "to enable" sounds like activating a feature, a button or anything similar.

What about

> 1. X is an app that allows you to do Y.
> 2. X is an app that helps you to do Y.
> 3. X is an app that simplifies to do Y.

Which version suits best, you have to decide from the context.

1. Without the app you are not allowed or not capable of doing Y.
2. 3. The app assists doing Y, either by quickening the process of doing Y or providing additional information etc.

Comment: Good point. I think I'll use "helps". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it can be inferred from context that X is an app, "X allows you to do Y." I might throw an adverb in at the end like "efficiently", "quickly", " easily"; if that would be accurate. Or "X enables quality Ying."